# How to extract values from Eureka forms in swift to local variables?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

While I try to pass it to temporary variables it doesn't seem to happen.

Although there are no errors while building the app, once I try to enter a value for "rateOfPaddy", it fails, citing "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong, either related to Swift or Eureka?

```
    form +++ Section()
                <<< DateTimeRow() {
                    $0.tag = "RecordDateTag"
                    $0.title = "Date"
                    $0.value = NSDate()
                    }.cellSetup { cell, row in
                        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                    }.onCellHighlight { _ in
                        if let dateInput = formInput["RecordDateTag"] as? String {
                            self.dateInputValue = dateInput
                        }
                    }.onCellUnHighlight { _ in
                        if let dateInput = formInput["RecordDateTag"] as? String {
                            self.dateInputValue = dateInput
                        }
                }
```

I used .onChange callback to check and pass the information to local variables, which was of no use. .onCellHighlight and .onCellUnHighlight combination didn't do the trick either!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling values function as documented [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#how-to-get-the-form-values)

You can create a method like below and call it from onChange callbacks

```
func updateValues() {
    let allFormData = formInput.values()

    if let dateInput = allFormData["RecordDateTag"] as? String {
        self.dateInputValue = dateInput
    }
}
```

Comment: I had it done as you said, and I was able to extract the values. But I would like to mention that you have erred in your syntax.                                    func updateValues() {
    let allFormData = formInput.values()

    if let dateInput = allFormData["RecordDateTag"] as? String {
        self.dateInputValue = dateInput
    }
}

Comment: Also, I believe onChange isn't required. Once the form is instantiated, the values seem to be saved into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The error **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** means that you are trying to unwrap an optional that has *nil* as a value.

Verify that every **formInput[KEY]** has a value of the type you expect before forcing the unwrap with the **as!**

You could benefit from the Optional Binding

```
if let value = formInput["Some"] as? Int
{
    //Value exist and is an Int
}
else
{
    print("Not an Int")
}
```

For More references:

[Swift Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338)

[Swift Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: It did help. A very foundational mistake that I did. Also, I did update the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @Shyam Based on the code you shared I don't see anything wrong, if you are not getting the value expected from `formInput["RecordDateTag"]` might be that there is no value for that key or that the value stored is not a String. Put a breakpoint there and verify the data type at that point. Also, where are you instantiating the dictionary?

Comment: You were point on! I had instantiated the dictionary within the method which creates the form. Once, I had it outside, I was able to pass the values.